# HMR not working within .NET Identity MVC Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webpack, webpack-hmr

I'm just setting up a new MVC project using .NET Core 2.1. I've configured Webpack for TypeScript/SASS compilation etc along with HMR (Hot Module Reload).

When setting all of this up I just had a simple HomeController with a single Index view and all was working correctly. I've now just added the scaffolded .NET Identity pages which get added to a new 'Identity' area in the project.

Here's my project structure:

[image]

The problem is that HMR seems to be broken within this area. I get the following console error when running the project:

> :58109/Identity/Account/dist/__webpack_hmr:1 Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

At first I thought this looked wrong but then I checked URL it's using on the Home/Index page (where HMR is working) and that was:

> http://localhost:58109/dist/__webpack_hmr

..so I'm not really sure what's going on or what the URL *should* be.

I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1204) which suggests adding `HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"` to the `WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions` in my Startup.cs. I have tried this and it did not help.

I have the following in my Startup.cs, as required:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
    {
        HotModuleReplacement = true,
        //HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"
    });
}
```

and my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const dirName = 'wwwroot/dist';
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
console.log('env:' + process.env.NODE_ENV);

module.exports =  {
    mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
    entry: { main: './wwwroot/js/app.ts' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                loader: 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node-modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[c|a]ss$/,
                use: [
                    'css-hot-loader',
                    //'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            config: {
                                ctx: {
                                    env: devMode ? 'development' : 'production'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'images',
                            publicPath: 'images'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(dirName, {}),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "bundle.css",
            chunkFilename: "bundle.css"
        })
    ]
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by changing changing my `publicPath` from `'dist/'` to `'/dist/'`. It seems the HMR needs the forward slash at the start to make sure it get's the correct location for __webpack_hmr.